# Get the width of parent <td> from angularjs directive template

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angular-directive

Im trying to figure out if its possible to get the width of the parent  my directive is going to be placed in.
Keeping it simple I have some directive `my-directive` which Im placing inside of a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><my-directive ..../></td>
<td><my-directive ..../></td>
<td><my-directive ..../></td>
<td><my-directive ..../></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And inside my-directive  Iwant to know the width of my parent `<td>` so I could display my content properly - with more or less data according to the width

Can it be done?

Update:
My HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td width="85%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col C 85</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><trim value="Some value a"></trim></td>
            <td>Some value b</td>
            <td>Some value c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('trim', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        value: '@'
    },
    template: "{{value | limitTo:6}}"
  };
}
```

);

From within the template I can limit by a constant I define (or pass by, from outside. But I want to change that, to know myself, from within that directive if I should trim the text or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the parent element using [angular's jqlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), a subset of jquery in the link function. The link function is to provide the behavior to your directive, in this function you can get the directive element and modify it at run time according to your need.

```
 angular.directive('myDirective', [function($document) {
 return {
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
        var parent = element.parent();// will give an array
        var parentWidth = parent[0].offsetWidth;
        //modify/truncate your attribute.value depending upon the parentWidth. 
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasnt aware of that. Can I then pass this parent variable and make use of it inside my template function?

Comment: A sample code will be appreciable. Where is your template function?

Comment: I updated the main question with more details. thank you